# How to Create Histogram from PGM Image

Tags: c, histogram, pgm

I need to create a single greyscale histogram of a PGM image for a class project. I already have the code to read the PGM image. However I don't completely understand how to count the unique pixel values. I don't need to output a graph or anything like that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code for reading PGM image
http://sun.iwu.edu/~shelley/sie/zoo/journal/pgm.c.html

Comment: You need to be more specific - do you want separate histograms for the R/G/B components, or do you want a single histogram for intensity, or some other quantity ?

Comment: I believe one single histogram. The assignment just says to compute the greyscale histogram.

Comment: OK - except the code you linked to seems to create an RGB image. If your input file is greyscale though then I presume the R/G/B components will all have the same value ? If so then you can just histogram one of them ?

Comment: potential duplicated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455343/displaying-histogram-pixel-values-from-pgm-image-p5-using-pure-c-without-any-i

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo code, assuming 8 bit greyscale image:

```
int histogram[256] = { 0 };     ; init histogram of all possible grey values to all zero

for i = 0 to rows - 1           ; for each row
    for j = 0 to cols - 1       ; for each col
        p = image[i][j]         ; get pixel value
        histogram[p]++          ; increment histogram bin
```

Comment: Thanks I think this might help. I just need to figure out how to call it.